# Adding registration tokens in an empty device group throws bad request in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have one device group per user for our mobile app. When a new user sign up, a new device group with registration token is created via `create` operation from app server and its notification key is stored with user data.

When a user sign out of the app, its registration token is removed from the notification key via `remove` operation as we don't want to send personal notification for that user to that device anymore. This step returns same notification key.

When a user sign in again, we try to add the registration token via `add` operation using the stored notification key. This action returns  `400 (Bad Request)` status from Firebase server.

Is this expected behavior? If so, how to handle the above use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification key for a device group is removed as soon as the token count  reaches zero.

I ended up using topics instead of device groups for this use case.